# JSP : Redirecting to other page by form or by response.sendRedirect

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```
<form action="welcome.jsp">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>
```

**OR**

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
```

Is there any difference between both of them or just we have to click the submit button in first one and other one will go directly to welcome.jsp

Answer (score 0):

we cant compare, one is Java and another is HTML

`response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");` in this case we don't need to invoke any event.

where as in case of `submit` we require submit or any other event.

depends upon your requirement you can use any of them.